# What to use instead of --no-ri for gem install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

```
gem update --system
gem install xxxx --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

gives: `invalid option: --no-ri` and `invalid option: --no-rdoc`, what is the new command line option?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [new option](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#installupdate-options-2) is `--no-document` or `-N`.

From `gem help install`:

```
  Deprecated Options:
        --[no-]rdoc                  Generate RDoc for installed gems
                                     Use --document instead
        --[no-]ri                    Generate ri data for installed gems.
                                     Use --document instead
```

Comment: Note that when installing gems with [bundler](https://bundler.io) no documentation is installed by default.

Answer (score -2):

Run the below command.

```
gem install bundler --no-force
```